# Traceback - Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

Hi a fairly new python programmer here.

Currently, I'm working on a first setup for a variational autoencoder.
Here my plan is to build an encoder and decoder separately and join them together afterwards.

```
encoder_input = Input(NUM_DATA, name='encoder_input')
encoded = Dense(32)(encoder_input)
encoded = Dropout(0.4)(encoded)
encoded = LeakyReLU()(encoded)
z_mu = Dense(LATENT_DIM, name='latent_mu')(encoded)
z_sigma = Dense(LATENT_DIM, name='z_sigma')(encoded)
z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(LATENT_DIM,))([z_mu,z_sigma])

encoder = Model(encoder_input,z)
encoder.summary()

---------------------------------------------

decoder_input = Input(LATENT_DIM, name='decoder_input')
decoded = Dense(32)(z)
decoded = Dropout(0.4)(decoded)
decoded = LeakyReLU()(decoded)
decoder_output = Dense(NUM_DATA, name='decoder_output')(decoded)

decoder = Model(z, decoder_output)
decoder.summary()
```

The encoder modelling works just fine.

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 encoder_input (InputLayer)     [(None, 500)]        0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)                  (None, 32)           16032       ['encoder_input[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 dropout (Dropout)              (None, 32)           0           ['dense[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 leaky_re_lu (LeakyReLU)        (None, 32)           0           ['dropout[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 latent_mu (Dense)              (None, 1)            33          ['leaky_re_lu[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 z_sigma (Dense)                (None, 1)            33          ['leaky_re_lu[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 lambda (Lambda)                (None, 1)            0           ['latent_mu[0][0]',              
                                                                  'z_sigma[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 16,098
Trainable params: 16,098
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The decoder part sadly resulted in a warning and a Valueerror:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Functional model inputs must come from `tf.keras.Input` (thus holding past layer metadata). They cannot be the output of a previous non-Input layer. Here, a tensor specified as input to "model_1" was not an Input tensor, it was generated by layer "lambda".
Note that input tensors are instantiated via `tensor = tf.keras.Input(shape)`.
The tensor that caused the issue was: Tensor("lambda/add:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)


Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("encoder_input:0", shape=(None, 500), dtype=float32) at layer "dense". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

As far as i understand it, the problem originates from the connection between the lambda layer and the decoder-part. I'm sadly not quite sure why that happens, because i tried the same in another file - with no such issue.

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 encoder_input (InputLayer)     [(None, 500)]        0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 dense_2 (Dense)                (None, 32)           16032       ['encoder_input[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 dropout_2 (Dropout)            (None, 32)           0           ['dense_2[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 leaky_re_lu (LeakyReLU)        (None, 32)           0           ['dropout_2[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 latent_mu (Dense)              (None, 1)            33          ['leaky_re_lu[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 z_sigma (Dense)                (None, 1)            33          ['leaky_re_lu[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 lambda (Lambda)                (None, 1)            0           ['latent_mu[0][0]',              
                                                                  'z_sigma[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 16,098
Trainable params: 16,098
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________




Model: "decoder"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)        [(None, 1)]               0         
                                                                 
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 32)                64        
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_2 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 32)                0         
                                                                 
 decoder_output (Dense)      (None, 500)               16500     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 16,564
Trainable params: 16,564
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Even though i copied the code 1 by 1 - the Error Message still persists.

For Information:

- Keras-Version: 2.9.0
- TensorFlow-Version: 2.13.0
- Using a Juypter Notebook in Pycharm

Thank you in Advance!

***EDIT:*** Turns out disabling eager execution resolves it.

Tried already:

- different version of Keras
- reinstalled keras and Tensorflow
- without `decoder = Model(z, decoder_output)` the error message disappears. Keeping this line of code in the long run in some form would be preferred.